# App Transport Security: Which method for RESTful APIs? `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` or `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`

Tags: ios, rest, security

I upgraded to Xcode 7.0.1 where the project targets iOS 9. If I would like to permit RESTful APIs with HTTP, should I use `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` or `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`? What advantage does which have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use *NSAllowsArbitraryLoads* and also use *NSExceptionDomains*, instead of disabling all https according to [App-Transport-Security-Technote](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/). However, if it is your own server that is http only, you should consider using a free certificate from [Let’s Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) in about a month instead.

Comment: Thanks, @Gillsoft AB. Would you care to share your thoughts about the pros/cons?

Comment: Tapjoy's iOS SDK recommends `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` in the `info.plist` but there is no explanation

Comment: If you also want proper usage of https you can add that domain to NSExceptionDomains, which you can't with your other option.